# How to build secure server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, security, server, backend

I would like to build server with node JavaScript and mongo database for sign up and sign in and maybe for payments
I searched what topics i need to learn for example authentication
But i would like to find some docs or an online course for that
Maybe you have some recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use API authentication for your server. I'm suggesting JWT authentication for the NodeJS Server.

You can refer to the below guide to set up JWT authentication to your server.

[Authentication API with JWT Token in NodeJS](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-build-authentication-api-with-jwt-token-in-nodejs/)

Comment: Thanks will check it out